# How to connect Hive database using baseline from python?

Tags: python-3.x, hive

Please help me whether any alternate way to connect Hive database.

I have hive database in HDFS platform, on daily bases I connect the database using below method.

`Open putty >> Connect Jump host server >> connect SSH with my user id/pwd >> impersonate our service account with my login password >> pass KERBROS auth file through KNIT >> connect hiv DB with baseline >> finally entered to my project database/tables`

Is there any way to connect same method in Python? I used Jumpssh and connected till using my user id/pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using python. I am showing one way using  pyodbc.
So,
step 1 - you need to create a odbc DSN in your windows or linux.
step 2 - you can use pyodbc to connect to hdfs.

```
import pyodbc 
# Configuration settings for the ODBC connection
cfg = {'DSN': 'hivedb', 'host': 'abc.com','port': 0050,'username': 'foo', 'password': 'bar'}
# Create connection
conn_string='DSN=%s;  database=default;AuthMech=3;UseSASL=1; UID=%s; PWD=%s; SSL=1;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1;CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1' %(cfg['DSN'], cfg['username'], cfg['password'])
cursor = conn1.cursor()
cursor.execute("Truncate Table default.temp")
```

You can use pandas to store the selected data.

Comment: Thanks Roy for sharing the details, I will test and confirm. Using ODBC will not have any performance or latency issues right?